# Iterate over Wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia

I would like to research something about the language used to describe people on Wikipedia.  My script is ready and passes tests, but I have one problem: I don't know how to request every Wikipedia biography page.

Does anyone know how to get a list of Wikipedia urls and/or get some sort of "next" url?  Just seeing biography urls would be a plus.

Answer (score 1):

In theory all biographies should be in the subcategories of [Category:People by gender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:People_by_gender)

Then you could use [PetScan](https://petscan.wmflabs.org/) (with CSV output or similiar) or [MediaWiki API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Physics) with categorymembers feature to retrieve articles, but be warned: those are A LOT!